# Paypal NVP API with Django

Tags: python, django, paypal

I am looking into using the paypal NVP API to allow users to pay on my website for a recurring subscription.

I have a few questions about the requirements.  Will my site have to meet the "PCI Compliance" stuff.  I guess I will have to get an SSL certificate and is there anything else that is required or that I need to know about?

Comment: I think I've read somewhere, someone implemented a reusable app for the paypal API. You'll probably find it if you google around.

Comment: yeah, I think django-paypal is set up for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing forcing you to meet PCI Compliance and use SSL, but you should anyway to limit your liability and inspire a little customer trust.

I thought I read something on the [Satchmo](http://satchmoproject.com) Developer's Google group about a person implementing PayPal NVP and having a patch.

Comment: Nice, that website was down yest. but seems to be fine today!  What do you mean by having a patch?

Comment: Sorry, I think I confused the PayPal acronyms NVP is already implemented its WPS (Websites Payment Standard?) that is not and there is a patch to enable WPS.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit out of date, but I wanted to add a note that I've recently released an [open source Python API to the PayPal NVP interface](http://www.chickenwingsw.com/scratches/python/paypal-on-python).

Comment: django-paypal already does a lot of this stuff and more.  Maybe you should just contribute to that project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure mine was written first.